# Difference between sqrt(Double) and sqrt(x:Double)

Tags: autocomplete, swift

I was making custom operators (`≠,≈,∑,√`) and the square root implementation is interesting. I wrote

```
prefix func √ (item:Double) -> Double {
    return sqrt(item)
}
```

It has 5 autocompletes when you type in `sqrt(`, 2 of which return Double. The second one gives you an error, and if you auto fix it removes the `x:`. What is the difference between them, why is the second one in autocomplete if it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three of the things you see in the autocomplete popup are `sqrt` function overloads -- they use the same function name, but different parameter types. This way you can remember `sqrt` means "square root" and use that name regardless of whether you're working with `Float`, `Double`, or `CGFloat` numbers. (It also means that if you want to create a `√` operator as an alias for `sort, you'll need to create three versions of it.)

The other two, appearing as `sqrt(Double)` and `sqrtf(Float)` in the autocomplete popup, are imported C API (and probably the underlying implementation of the other three `sqrt` functions). Those probably shouldn't be showing up, so I'd recommend [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Ok, but why does autocomplete think that `x:Double` is a viable parameter for `sqrt(`? Also `sqrt(Double)` is the one that works, so that is not a bug. Strangely enough, remove the `import Foundation` at the beginning of a file and all sqrt functions disappear.

Comment: The blue-oval placeholder text Xcode inserts for autocomplete is from the function's declaration -- it tells you what kind of value you can insert as a parameter. But it's just placeholder text for you to replace; it's not meant to be inserted verbatim as a parameter.

Comment: That functions disappear when you remove an `import` statement isn't strange at all. `sqrt` and friends are defined in the `Darwin` module, which contains all the basic Unix APIs and is transitively imported by Foundation.